# PHP - Session for making product id persistent?

Tags: php, mysql, session, get

I am creating a product database/site with php and mysql. I have started down the road of using a session variable to store my current record id for later reference on future pages. As I have gotten a little further it has dawned on me that this may not be the ideal method as when I want to display a link to a different product, I don't have an easy way to update the session variable to the new id.

Imagine if you will that you were on a product page for product id 73. The session variable would be $_SESSION['id'] = 73. Now you perform a search in the system and find a new product you want to view. You click the link and are redirected to the "product page" which is expecting to access the session variable to know which product to display, but at this point the variable is still set to 73.

Is the only/best way to make this process work with GET and by appending my variable to the url string? What is the recommended process for this scenario? I was trying to avoid using GET because I thought session variables were the preferred method for this type of thing and I was trying to have a clean URL string.

Comment: There's no reason to use GET for this.  Why is it that you say "I want to display a link to a different product, I don't have an easy way to update the session variable to the new id."  Why not?  You say `$_SESSION['id'] = $newid`

Comment: @Unipartisandev: And what if a particular page has a list of links to different products.  How will those links work?

Comment: @Unipartisandev : David's comment is the exact issue. If I have search results with multiple links, I can't reset the session variable until I hit another page. Yes, I could then set the session upon landing on the product page, but in order to do so, I still have to to pass the information in the URL string first. So, in my opinion, there is no point in even using the session variable at that point.

Comment: I say do what works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought session variables were the preferred method for this type of thing

Not at all.  While you may have a single "product.php" *page* for the purpose of simplifying and re-using code, you don't have a single "product" *resource*.  Any request to view the details of a given product is a request for a different resource.  According to HTTP standards, the URL for that request should be different so that the URL can identify that resource.

In probably most cases, that ends up looking something like this:

```
product.php?id=123
```

So as you can imagine any unique product would product a unique URL by using a numeric identifier.  This isn't, however, the only way to do it.

> I was trying to have a clean URL string

You still can.  And there are a number of ways to do that.  A lot of modern web frameworks, for example, may be able to derive the identifier from the format of the request URL.  So you may be able to use something like this:

```
products/123
```

This looks much more RESTful because it maintains the identifier as a part of the URL rather than a value appended to the URL.  Additionally, it pluralizes the `products` component of the resource which more accurately indicates that one is requesting an item (123) from a collection (products).

Depending on the framework or tools you use, you may also be able to use a named identifier.  So the URL might look something like this:

```
products/my-awesome-product
```

This can work if there is a unique contextual name for any given product, as opposed to (or perhaps in addition to) a unique numeric system identifier.

---

The point is, using session state for simple resource navigation is definitely *not* the preferred approach.  And it very quickly becomes a problem, as you're now finding.  The use of session variables introduces a dependency on server-side state.  HTTP is, by design, stateless.  GET requests do not imply state, the request itself should carry the information for what is being requested.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer so thoroughly. I'm not sure where I got the idea that a session variable was the better approach, but as you stated, obviously I've found out on my own that it's not actually the case and you've done a nice job explaining it.

Answer (score 2):

its not useful to have a "clean url", because then your products cant be indexed by search engines like google.
you should always have an own url for every product.
you can make "speaking urls" like /category/product and translate it with url rewrite.
session variables are better used for persistent things like login data.

Comment: I just had an epiphany.  I never though about search engine indexing in regards to GET before.

Comment: @cari : good point about search engine indexing, I hadn't thought of that either. In this case however, it's for an intranet site so it doesn't apply, but absolutely worth remembering for future projects.

Answer (score 1):

> I thought session variables
>   were the preferred method for this type of thing and I was trying to
>   have a clean URL string

**never use sessionVariables for such issues!**

example where you could have problems using session Variables:

lets say, your product url looks like:

```
www.abc.com/product/bmw-q7
```

and the id of this Product is 73 saved in session, soo the user would like to bookmark your url? and later he clicked the bookmarked link, at this moment, there is no id saved in the NEW started session.

so the prefered way is to append the id in the url:

```
www.abc.com/product/bmw-q7?id=73
```

or BETTER if you use htaccess-mode-rewrite:

```
www.abc.com/product/bmw-q7/73
```